# Is there a programmatic way to determine RUs used for DocumentDB bindings on an Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Function bindings make it extremely simple to wire up DocumentDB inputs and Outputs.  However, from an operations standpoint how can I monitor when my app nearing its RU allotment?  Is that knowledge something that I give up by using the bindings?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure Cosmos DB bindings in Azure Function [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#input---configuration),  there is no such property or method to get input or output RUs directly. As I know, you could check the `metrics` on portal or `Diagnostics logs` in the Azure Storage to get RUs usage of your cosmos db account.

Also, you could use [Cosmos DB SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb._resource_response.getrequestcharge) in Azure Function to get RUs of operations. If you have to use bindings, you could give feedback to ms about your requirements.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I agree about the documentation does not say anything about RU tracking.  Also I do not see anything related to the Cosmos in the captured logs.  Ultimately I am looking for a way to use the bindings before eschewing their use in favor of the SDK.